# how is apt-cache implemented

Tags: linux, unix, caching, apt, apt-get

I am looking at the apt-cache implementation. 
How does apt-cache create and updates the local package cache? Is it periodic or manual? As far as my investigation, it is manual (apt-get update).

When we run "apt-get update", does it download all the packages information or does the current state of cache (like all package information and version) be sent to the server then the client machine (where apt-get update is running) gets only what has changed compared with local cache information?

fyi, I am using Linux 4.4.0-18362-Microsoft. "apt-config dump" command output doesn't show "APT::Cache::Generate".

Comment: See here: https://sources.debian.org/src/apt/1.8.4/cmdline/apt-cache.cc/

Answer (score 0):

When you run `apt update`, it downloads all of the changes that are not the latest. Therefore returning `Ign`. The cache is generated automatically on a daily basis (to my knowledge): https://askubuntu.com/questions/997089/why-do-both-cron-and-systemd-execute-automatic-upgrades